# My custom listview scrolls back to first element instantly when scrolling up. How to prevent that and make a smooth scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, user-interface, adapter

I am trying to create a custom listview like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8ZOc.png

Currently I managed to create it but there is a problem. For example when there are 8 items, it loads the first 4, then loads the remiaining items as you scroll down. When scrolling down, it works fine.

However, when scrolling back up from bottom, at the middle of list, it instantly moves to top, skipping 2-3-4. items. Then you can scroll down normally again, but when scrolling up, it instantly goes to top of the list.

How can i prevent this from happening?

Here is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    String headers[];
    String image_urls[];

    List<MyMenuItem> menuItems;
    ListView mylistview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        menuItems = new ArrayList<MyMenuItem>();
        headers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.header_names);
        image_urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_urls);


        for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            MyMenuItem item = new MyMenuItem(headers[i], image_urls[i]);
            menuItems.add(item);
        }

        mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(this, menuItems);
        mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyMenuItem {

    private String item_header;
    private String item_image_url;

    public MyMenuItem(String item_header, String item_image_url){
        this.item_header=item_header;
        this.item_image_url=item_image_url;
    }

    public String getItem_header(){
        return item_header;
    }

    public void setItem_header(String item_header){
        this.item_header=item_header;
    }

    public String getItem_image_url(){
        return item_image_url;
    }

    public void setItem_image_url(String item_image_url){
        this.item_image_url=item_image_url;
    }


}
```

---

```
public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    List<MyMenuItem> menuItems;

    MenuAdapter(Context context, List<MyMenuItem> menuItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.menuItems = menuItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return menuItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return menuItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return menuItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivMenu;
        TextView tvMenuHeader;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tvMenuHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuHeader);
            holder.ivMenu = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivMenuItem);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        MyMenuItem row_pos = menuItems.get(position);

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(row_pos.getItem_image_url())
             //   .placeholder(R.drawable.empty)
             //   .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(holder.ivMenu);

        holder.tvMenuHeader.setText(row_pos.getItem_header());

        Log.e("Test", "headers:" + row_pos.getItem_header());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MyActivity">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your xml file of Listview.

Comment: this happens bcoz to inflate the view along with image for a particular row takes little time and with in tat it gets scrolled more and hence we dn see one or two rows.. i too searching a sol for this :-/

Comment: I added xml file of Listview.

Comment: Panther thanks for help! I used a placeholder image with the same size of imamges i load so it kinda looks better for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy loading mechanism to load your image data.
There is one nice example [here](http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134)